# selenium with chromedriver not working

Tags: behat

I use selenium 3 and chrome browser to test but selenium doesn't launch chrome browser. I set chromedriver path: `usr/local/bin`

this is code behat.yml:

```
default:
        suites:
            default:
                bundle: MedBundle
                contexts:
                    - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\FeatureContext
                    - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\AjouterContext
        extensions:
            Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
            Behat\MinkExtension:
                base_url: http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php
                goutte: ~
                browser_name: 'chrome'
                javascript_session: selenium2
                selenium2:
                    wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
                sessions:
                    default:
                        symfony2: ~
```

I have this problem:

[image]

help me for resolve this problem , I am blocked

Comment: help me please ...

Comment: Look at these first: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6djs/running-behat2-tests-with-different-browsers, http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/js7k/running-selenium-server-standalone-and-cromedriver, http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5rxn/taking-screenshots-of-failed-scenarios-in-behat3

Comment: I download selenium server 2.43.1 and I use commande for lunch chromium but I have this problem
http://imgur.com/a/8jeKL